# This place is AWESOME!

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Not really a question but an incredibly grateful comment. I am so thankful for this site's creation. I only recently became aware of it having a lot of programming questions lately. Seems any and all questions I ever ask are already here so again, THANK YOU FOR EXISTING!

Comment: Why this post is'nt flagged? Is'nt this off-topic?

Comment: @SE_Sucks because once upon a time, when dragons flew in the sky and unicorns roamed the lands, we allowed fun here.

Answer (score 68):

No, thank YOU FOR EXISTING!!! :)

Because after all, [Stack Overflow is You](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/stack-overflow-is-you/).<sup>*</sup>

<sub>* most of the time</sub>