# My compliments for Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This place is AWESOME!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome)
>   [A Thanksgiving Thank You](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/a-thanksgiving-thank-you)

I just wanted to give you my compliments for creating and looking after Stack Overflow. I found it few days ago (how could I live without it?) and I find it very very useful. Well done. Thank you.

Comment: This *must* be a duplicte. And yet I'd feel like a [...] searching for dupes, let alone voting to close :-)

Comment: Is indeed a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31071/a-thanksgiving-thank-you

Comment: to be honest quite often I have troubles to find if there is any similar/duplicate questions. But I have not search last time though :-( but you all sorted out very nicely :-p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Of course, if you like what you see the *best* (*) way IMO to pay compliments to stackoverflow is to stick around, answer a few questions occasionally, etc. Welcome to the community. Leaving is not allowed ;-p (unless you annoy Jeff...).

(*=although I'm pretty sure the team also love seeing the occasional (and much-deserved) "thanks", "awesome", etc)

Comment: leaving is allowed also if your doctor says you need to sleep.

Comment: it is not so funny :-) last two nights stackoverflow made me stay late :-) maybe I should talk to my doctor?

Answer (score 4):

thanks Radek! and as Marc points out, the best way to say thanks is to "pay it forward" and contribute a little to answering your fellow programmers' questions ..

Comment: well if I was able I would anserwer :-)