# Praise for the error page

Tags: discussion, 500-server-error

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This place is AWESOME!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome)

I'd just ran into an error on Area 51, and was re-aquainted with the `Oops! Something Bad Happened!` page.  I have to say, it's one of the best I've seen, and I really appreciate that

- The site is up front about the fact that something went horribly wrong.
- The issue is logged with 0 effort on my part.
- I'm told I didn't mess things up.

So thanks for doing something right.

~Ross

Comment: On behalf of the folks at Stack Overflow et al, with whom I have no professional or personal relationship, you're welcome.

Comment: It's not worth another post, but I'd like to say thankyou for the [404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/Tryingtogettheerrorpage) [pages](http://superuser.com/questions/Tryingtogettheerrorpage) of the [trilogy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/Tryingtogettheerrorpage), with [serverfault's](http://serverfault.com/questions/Tryingtogettheerrorpage) being easily the best!

Comment: I totally agree @Mark.  It's nice to know someone on the web can be professional and have a sense of humor.

Comment: Not quite an _exact_ duplicate, but close enough in the land where [we hate fun](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/01/stack-overflow-where-we-hate-fun/). Don't let me stop you from _workin on ur problemz_, though :)

Comment: I also love the random funny WORKIN ON UR PROBLEMZ pictures.  :)