# Voting to close should only increment the counter next to the close link

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I just opened the flag dialog intending to submit a generic mod flag, but I changed my mind about flagging and submitted a close vote instead. I never left the dialog, though; I just selected the "it doesn't belong here" option.

Usually, voting to close causes the text of the `close` link to change to `close (1)`, but in this case no change was made. However, I am now seeing `flag (1)`:

[image: link | edit | close | flag (1)]

I suspect that this is an artifact of the logic saying "when a vote to close is cast, increment the counter by the link that opened the dialog," which made perfect sense before the flag dialog was upgraded to its current feature-rich state [back in January](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/).

> **EDIT**:
> To be clear, this did go through properly as a close vote, and upon reload the page displays
>
> ```
> link | edit | close (1) | flag
> ```
>
> This bug is merely, in Grace Note's words, "a pre-refresh artifact on the page."

Comment: This is interestingly backwards from the usual point where flagging something with a close reason will auto-convert to a close vote if you have them remaining. Did that (1) stick around? Is it in your flag report? Or is it just a pre-refresh artifact on the page?

Comment: "Not really a question..." with 18 points, ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @Daniel That's how you know it's not a real question; a real question would've had ~2

Comment: FWIW, it's [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I suspect that this is an artifact of the logic saying "when a vote to close is cast, increment the counter by the link that opened the dialog,

Your suspicion, Watson, could not be closer to the truth.