# Stackoverflow and related sites are gaming me

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [This place is AWESOME!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome)

Not a question. Rather an observation. So the moderators can close quickly if they want.

I now find while Googleing for mostly technical or programming questions that if I find a really good answer I find myself looking around the page to up-vote to show my appreciation that his or her answer helped me solve my problem. Of course many sites are not stackoverflow like so I can't. Perhaps the ability to up-vote might spread across the net?

So Jeff, Joel and helpers. Keep up the good work.

Comment: You Googel? Cool!

Comment: Yes its like Google but its a futuristic AI cloud that understands exactly what I want.

Comment: excellent, and as always .. pay it forward!