# How can I thank Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Is there a way to send a thanks message to Stack Overflow or any of the individual Stack Exchange sites, aside from sending an email? I want to thank Stack Overflow for being an awesome live QA site. It helps people a lot.

Comment: Ask your questions, post answers when you have them. That's all the thanks we need. :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27269/this-place-is-awesome

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The best way to thank Stack Exchange is to be a part of it:

- ask amazing questions
- give great answers
- improve existing content by editing
- help out with moderation once you have the rep

Comment: I heard they also like it if you send chocolate or pizza to their offices.

Comment: That's great and all, but I think that there should be a place to type your happiness.