# Why do some SE sites have looser policy than others

Tags: discussion, area-51, policy

I know that Stack Exchange requires questions to be specific, unambiguous, and having single-solution.
For example, in the [tour page](https://stackexchange.com/tour) (my emphasis):

> Ask about...
> **Specific issues** within each site's area of expertise
> Real problems or questions that you've encountered

and, as immediately following,

> Don't ask about...
> Questions that are **primarily opinion-based**
> Questions with **too many possible answers** or that would require an extremely long answer

Similarly, it was remarked [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum) that

> Stack Exchange encourages specific questions that have a specific, canonical answers."

A quick glance in [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) gives me the impression that several proporsals are probably too vague, too broad, or too aesthetics-based to reach attention, though it's just my guess:
the [literature proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature), the [tea proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93038/tea), and the [ethics proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95466/ethics), among others.

Of all SE sites, it is generally noticed, [say in this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/254355/why-does-stack-overflow-have-so-many-negative-critics), that [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) has quite strict policy.
This is understandable, as SO has gained tremendous popularity, and everyday there are a huge number of junk posts swarming all over into it.

However, certain SE sites seem to maintain looser standard than others.
How can an request for suggestion of action in a certain situation in an [academy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) or [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) have a single "right" answer,
or how can a [worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/), a possible continuation of a fictional situation, be the most likely one among other competitors,
as does [mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) or [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/)?

Is this not double standard? Is the principle of **non-opinion-based** and **allowing specific answers**, though well meant, simply ill-defined?

So it seems the rule of each site is decided by adminstrators of their own.
Then again, why can't we create literature, ethics, or tea site? I don't understand.

Comment: Sure, some topics are less technical than others. Does not necessarily prevent a site from existing. About your three examples: see [Literature](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93238/literature), [Tea](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/93038/tea), and [Ethics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/95466/ethics). These are proposals yet to be launched, because they don't have enough users committing or contributing sample questions, not because someone is holding them back.

Comment: So, the strictness of SO is decided by their admins, not (as I assumed) by the general SE policy.

Comment: I think Stack Overflow to the laypersons's programming questions has become somewhat like Physics Overflow to general physics questions. Why hasn't someone open a new programming question site with looser standard (like physics SE)?

Comment: There is no such role as "admin" of a Stack Exchange site. And if there were, how exactly would they deal with 9000 new questions on Stack Overflow every day? One can't even read that many questions. If you want to learn how these sites really work, observe and participate.

Comment: Right.... as you can tell, I am new to this.... so I am just giving my quick, if not rash, observation. And surely I have just learned something. Anyway, may be you shall make your comment an answer so I may choose ? : P

Comment: you seem to be focusing on "softer" sites but if you look closer, most striking difference can be observed on "harder", software related sites. For things that really heavily deviate from Stack Overflow model take a look at question and answer norms at Code Golf, Software Recommendations, Code Review

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please see the blog post [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

We just had [a complaint to this effect](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4118/627) on Worldbuilding meta. The logic was the same as yours: Why are some questions allowed when they are opinion-based? There are several points to consider, in response:

- Not all questions on the sites you mentioned are opinion-based. Asking about typical processes for peer-review in academic journals, general company policy dealing with [X, Y or Z], or whether or not a given planetary system is likely to form are not opinion-based.
- There is a difference between simply subjective and overly subjective. If there's no way for determining which answer is the best, the questions is likely too subjective.
- The sites you mentioned are indeed more subjective than other sites. However, they have been careful to make it *clear* that there is an element of subjectivity to many of their questions, and they have outlined the boundaries of opinionated questions. I'd recommend looking at their help centers and per-site metas.

Answer (score 5):

The guidelines on the Stack Exchange tour page is just general guidelines. Each site has its own guidelines. In other words, those policies on each site are decided by Meta discussions among users and implemented by users, not by administrators. There are very well managed sites while there are some poorly managed sites. Everything depends on each site.

As @zaq commented, it's best for you to observe and participate.

Comment: As an maybe extreme example of a meta discussion leading to the re-scoping of NPR/Programmers/Software Engineering: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8056/new-site-name-and-scope-proposals

Comment: @rene for the sake of precision that change was more about bringing site name and description closer to the established scope. I for one have been following it for several months with primary purpose to [ensure that site scope stays the same](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286962/is-software-engineering-the-replacement-of-programmers#comment931106_286963) :)