# So how many people have stopped participating because of passive-aggressive harassment?

Tags: discussion

Since the new "be nice" rule, I've notice that a *lot* of responses while not overtly mean, are definitely passive-aggressive and in real life in a real business would result in being dis-invited from future meetings and possibly booted out the door for being a "bad culture fit".

The is driving away actual participants in droves, leaving mostly people who google an answer and never actually sign up to help.

What can be done to discourage this behavior and encourage genuinely friendly behavior?

Comment: Can you give some examples of the types of responses that you feel are passive-aggressive? Are downvotes passive-aggressive? Is closing a question passive-aggressive?

Comment: You really can't storm in and throw such accusations without solid examples, you just make things worse this way. If you don't want to share examples use the "contact us" link and send it in private to SE team.

Comment: You can achieve both your goals, to discourage this behavior and encourage genuinely welcoming behavior, simultaneously, and almost overnight with one simple change: make askers aware that like any other exchange, SE requires reciprocity. To get, you have to give. Reciprocity is respect. Reciprocity of effort. Reciprocity of assuming good faith. But even just the “reciprocity of effort”, alone, would go a long, long way. People who put effort into their own questions before asking others to donate effort on their behalf almost never suffer this passive aggressiveness you observe.

Comment: If you're talking about comments, this is exactly the type of things the "be welcoming" movement was supposed to address, and I'm not convinced it's gotten worse since then. (The "be nice" policy [has been around for years](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240839/the-new-new-be-nice-policy-code-of-conduct-updated-with-your-feedback), and I believe that's mostly been replaced now)

Comment: For what it's worth, people acting the way many new users here act (between asking 0-effort questions, ignoring requests for clarification and acting very entitled) would almost certainly run into problems in just about any workplace.

Comment: @DanBron I've seen this in action and it can come across as being patronizing if not carefully worded.

Comment: @Snow Seen what in action? Can you give me a couple examples?

Comment: @Dukeling I'm not convinced it's worse either. However I've been paying more attention to it and noticing it a lot more since the new "be nice" policy was implemented. To all the people asking for examples: This is exactly what I'm talking about. If you can't identify the behavior without being handed an example, there's no point in this discussion. What prompted it was a post on reddit that blew up so quickly with "me too!" and "I'll never log in to SO" that it has apparently been deleted.

Comment: @PushfPopf But without examples you don't have a case. I have the impression that users are more friendly (or unfriendly comments are removed more quickly), so what now?

Comment: I was reserving judgement, as it's not quite clear what exactly is being referred to, but as soon as we get, "If you need examples, there's no point", then there's no good faith going on.  The issue isn't clear, nor obvious what is being referred to.  If it's a reference to yet another, "SO sucks, amiright?" post...meh.

Comment: I'll just put it here: [Why does Stack Overflow have so many negative critics?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254355). Whether it's a dupe or not, it's up to you... (**please read the answers carefully**)

Comment: 'never actually sign up to help' - I don't blame them.  Who would want to sign up to be continually blamed tor objecting to teaching the same 'Computers 101' lessons every day, for free?  Better to not bother at all with helping on SO - it only leads to pain:(

Comment: @Somewhat Not surprisingly the discussion was closed. I'm actually not sure why I bothered to bring this up again. I'm sure this will be downvoted and closed soon too.

Comment: @PushfPopf There's nothing wrong with discussing what you see as an issue.  But...part of that discussion requires you to bring something to the table to actually *discuss*.  We don't know what you're talking about; you need to make it much clearer.

Comment: @PushfPopf It probably will unless you edit it to be more specific. Did something trigger this question? Still, examples? Plus, your title is asking "how many people have left", you text states "The is driving away actual partcipants in droves" without any proof, and the question you actually ask is "what can we do"...

Comment: _If you can't identify the behavior without being handed an example, there's no point in this discussion_ You have that the wrong way round. Obviously we can’t magically identify behaviour we haven’t seen, that’s not a sensible expectation. If you _have_ seen this, then it seems reasonable that you would be able to provide at least one example. If it’s as endemic as you profess, you should have no trouble providing lots of examples. But refusing to provide examples on the principal that everyone should already be able to work it out for themselves, does nothing but weaken your position

Comment: @Clive What prompted this was a thread on Reddit about being subtly (or not subtly) treated poorly on SO. It blew up, got huge with "me too!" responses and was then deleted. Picking out a few posts wouldn't be difficult but I don't want to make an example out of a small random selection of people with poor social skills. The question isn't "if" the question is "How can we make SO into a place that normal humans actually enjoy using?"

Comment: ...we don't count as normal humans?

Comment: Yeah I don’t really give much credence to posts on Reddit, about anything. If you want “passive-aggressive”, Reddit is usually where you go to find it, in my experience. Maybe it’s a left-brain v. right-brain thing. You don’t have to call people out by the way, you can just post the comments themselves with usernames redacted. And I’m afraid the question is still very much “if” for me, I don’t see any proof or even anecdotal evidence for your claims. Whether you consider me a “normal human” or not.

Comment: @PushfPopf Btw, I am almost reluctant to bring this up again, but since this seems to be another jab aimed at established users moderating... Have you seen [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/366733/1288408) (warning: language)? It's a sample of openly hostile comments posted by new users. That's the other side of the medal and the reason why some established users get a little miffed when being accused of being unwelcoming. NB, I see less of those comments nowadays, and I am thankful for that.

Comment: @ModusTollens I'll have to check it later. Can't do any risky clicks at work.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [some questions with the \[welcoming\] tag on Meta SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/welcoming?sort=votes&pageSize=30) for a perspective from the other side. Specifically about [disagreements about what's not welcoming](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370792), [the difficulty of the problem considering the diverse userbase](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/370993) and [demonizing the quality-concerned users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366858).

Comment: @Dukeling I've read them (most of them anyway). I think the crux of the issue is that SO's owner needs to decide if they're willing to include "nice" in the criteria for rating users even if it's at the expense of booting people who are technically excellent but do not get along well with other humans.

Comment: @PushfPopf So moderators and user moderators should be infallible. Their "niceness" should be rated. They spend hours moderating the site, but maybe they can't help getting a little terse now and then after addressing the umpteenth unresearched easy-to-google question asked in leet speach after an 8 hour workday...

Comment: @ModusTollens Maybe that's part of the problem; that SO is running on mostly-free labor. Employees can be held accountable and told how to behave. Volunteers no-so-much.

Comment: @PushfPopf The entire SE network can't work without volunteers.  Remove them, and the whole thing fails.  Hence why any ultimatums from SE will do nothing but destroy their business.

Comment: @PushfPopf But "nice" is subjective - that's the crux of the problem. People who are way on the wrong side of the line between "nice" and "not nice" (e.g. they go around swearing at everyone) get sorted out pretty quickly as it stands. When you start trying to zoom in on that line, and a smaller percentage agree that it's rude, you start running into problems.

Comment: @Dukeling It just occurred to me after hearing this for decades that "You get what you reward". If SO's point system was re-jiggered so users were rewarded for being nice instead of whatever causes people to hit the up-vote button now, I think things would change.

Comment: @PushfPopf Yeah, you'd stop rewarding expertise. Guess what happens to the expert answers in that scenario? And the experts?

Comment: @PushfPopf Is "being nice" not criticising a user for not using prepared statements in SQL queries? Because I've been told that was being unfriendly by them. Are downvotes unfriendly? Because I've been told they are.

Comment: @PushfPopf A lot of moderating actions are seen as "unfriendly" when new users don't read up on the rules. Are they the ones to judge what is "nice"?

Comment: @PushfPopf If you reward niceness, everyone will tend toward excessive / fake niceness and many will perceive that as a lot more toxic than it is now. Reducing or eliminating the reward for people who know what they're talking about will also reduce the number of people who know what they're talking about, which is pretty damning for a professional Q&A that strives to have high quality questions and answers. The niceness discussion is also 99% about comments, which are intended to be temporary, and rewarding that will take the focus away from the important part - the actual Q&A's.

Comment: @fbueckert 'then there's no good faith going on' - there is nothing but fath.  The impact of so-called 'passive-aggressive' responses is a belief.  Even the existence of such responses in significant numbers is a religious dogma.  Evidence is not required on a holy site like SO...... .oh wait....

Comment: Anecdotal: just now a comment on a question was asking to stop downvoting a question because of OP being a new contributor. That comment got upvotes and the post got pity-upvotes. As long as downvoting is seen as being unfriendly we can't win trying to keep the quality up. Discouraging. Demotivating.

Comment: @ModusTollens well, unfortunately, the site is now pwned by the uncaring majority:(

Answer (score 17):

In your title you ask how many people have left, which probably wouldn't be measurable even if you specified the constraints of the query more clearly.  Instead, I'll address the question in your body.

> What can be done to discourage this behavior and encourage genuinely friendly behavior?

If you see something that violates site policies, including the code of conduct, flag it.  Comment flags were recently overhauled to make it easier to see how to flag unkind or abusive comments.  Use your flags.

If you see a systematic problem on a site (not just a stray comment), bring it up *with specific examples* on that site's meta and ask the community how to improve things.  Helpful tip: these kinds of meta discussions go better if you approach with a question rather than a vague assertion.

Another thing you can do is to model good behavior.  Make sure your *own* comments and posts are constructive, welcoming, and free of passive-aggressiveness, snark, or ranting.  If you see somebody who needs a helping hand -- a pointer to the help, an edit that you can provide, etc -- then offer it if you can.  Be the change you want to see.

You might be labeling as "passive-aggressive" things that are not, like downvotes and close votes.  Those are important site functions that are explained in the help.

Comment: While I have no access to the "behind the scenes" activity, the "flag" button seems to be about as effective as the "cross-walk buttons" that do nothing but make the pedestrians feel like they have some control. A response would be nice like "we deleted the comment" or "user has been warned and will be banned if the behavior continues" would be most welcome. It would be especially wonderful if this applied equally to everybody, regardless of points or badges.

Comment: Moderators can't reply to comment flags, but if the flag was valid the comment gets deleted.  Users who get too many unkind/rude flags are automatically brought to the attention of moderators.  Specific corrective action is always going to be private between the moderators and the affected users.

Comment: @PushfPopf Why do you believe flags to be useless? You can see how flags were handled in you flag history. I see comments I flagged being deleted all the time.

Comment: @ModusTollens Especially for high-point users, there's still no (apparent) down-side to being an a-hole. Maybe a sidebar that lists actual actions like "recently banned users" would be useful. Like "User <userid> (Reputation <rep>) banned for two weeks for being unkind" would help.

Comment: @PushfPopf here is your list of high-rep users that are possible suspended: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/901680/finding-possible-suspended-users

Comment: @PushfPopf There is a down-side: gather enough "unfriendly" flags and you'll get suspended.

Comment: @ModusTollens This should be public. Like when people give the grocery store bad checks and they put up a sign at the cash register that says "X gave us a bad check". With (hundreds of thousands?) of users, the general membership has no idea that any particular people have been suspended, which makes the penalties invisible and largely ineffective.

Comment: But we don't hold a permanent grudge against users ... Nor do we believe that this community can't change over time. It took us 6 to 8 years to get here, give us some leeway to find the way out of here ...

Comment: @PushfPopf Of couse it _is_ public. It says so on their profile and their reputation points are set to 1.

Comment: Adding a sidebar would go against the current moderation process; we forgive and forget.  Someone's served their time, so they're welcome back as if it didn't happen.  Publicizing it doesn't do anything but add drama.  Naming and shaming doesn't work if the goal is changing someone's behaviour; it just leads to rubbernecking.

Comment: @ModusTollens That's not really public. It's like when the Vogons destroyed the Earth (HHGTTG) and said that the order had been on display in a basement on another planet. Nobody is going to go look at a specific user profile to see what happened unless they're way too invested. OVerall actions should be visible without doing any digging. Maybe even just a tote board like "30 users given 2 week bans today for being unkind"

Comment: @PushfPopf Yeah, why not establish a virtual pillory. Bring out the pitch fork while you're at it. Seriously. You still didn't bring up any live example of the behaviour you don't like on SE. Hint: if you find one, flag it. That's the tool to make the site better.

Comment: @PushfPopf please take the discussion of publicizing suspensions somewhere else.  It's tangential to this answer, it's not going to change anyway, and I'm getting pinged on every comment in this discussion.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Public Embarrassment is an effective tool for enforcing social norms and is right on point with the text you quoted "What can be done to discourage this behavior and encourage genuinely friendly behavior?"; While I thought things might be different now, I'm not surprised that this didn't get any more traction now than 2 years ago or 5 or more years ago. Every now and then I get irrationally hopeful that actual change will happen and SO will become a place that inspires new programmers instead of filling them with dread.

Comment: @PushfPopf - "Public Embarrassment is an effective tool" - No;  It's a tool to run off people you don't agree with.  "Public Embarrassment" is a passive-aggressive tool primarily used by insecure people.  If anyone attempted to do that to me, it wouldn't change my behavior, I am not swayed by the crowd.  I am not a sheep.

Comment: @rene Thanks! That's really interesting. I didn't know that users had access to the database.

Answer (score 3):

It is not easily possible to even estimate how many people have stopped participating, never mind the number who have stopped because of 'passive-aggressive' responses specifically.

Its may be failrly easy to estimate the number of accounts that ask one question and then become dormant, but differentiating between actual one-off users and one-account-per-question burner accounts is not easily possible.

Then there's the issue of identifying 'passive-aggressive' responses.  Many CoC violating responses are active-defensive, eg: 'No! We will not do all your homework', and many just defensive, eg: 'We cannot help if you don't copy/paste the code you actually tested'.

You would have to define what 'passive-agressive' means, and then the whole thing spirals into 'agressivegate' with a couple months of wasted meta effort that will eventually conclude that anything could be 'felt' as 'passive-agressive', and so it's better to not post anything at all. especially to new accounts.

SO is going to PHP in handbasket, and meta pseudo-rants like this question are buying the tickets.